# “We're getting your order ready to be shipped."

Tags: sentence-construction

> We're getting your order ready to be shipped.

I feel uncertain about this sentence. I understand if I write it in two sentences it will be fine.

> We're getting your order ready. Your order is ready to be shipped.

But can I combine them to form one single sentence? I think this sentence is supposed to be two sentence and should not be combined together. The first sentence is We're getting your order ready. And the second is Your order is ready to be shipped. Is this understanding right?

Comment: Where is the sentence?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.  When we finish our present task, the order will be ready to be shipped.  There are other ways to say it – *ready to ship, ready for shipping, ready for shipment* – but none of them is more right than another.

Answer (score 2):

Your examples have different meanings.

The first is fine.  It means that the order is not yet ready to be ship, but we are working on it.

The second example is grammatically correct, but contradictory, since if "We are getting your order ready" then it isn't "ready to be shipped."

Normally the single sentence with the "to infinitive" would be used, as in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct as-is. Your proposed split into two sentences would change the meaning. The order is **not** ready to be shipped. It will be after they're done getting it ready.

The main construction is "to get (something) ready **for** + *noun phrase*" or "to get something ready **to** (infinitive verb phrase)". Your example is the latter form. It means the thing is being prepared so that the action described by the verb or verb phrase can then take place.